# Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I want to add firebase to my project.
but I got this error message:

```
FirebaseError {code: "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration", message: "Messaging: We are unable to register the default s…). (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).", browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').", stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to registe…es/@firebase/messaging/dist/index.cjs.js:1951:32)"}
browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')."
code: "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
message: "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/index.cjs.js:1951:32)"
__proto__: Error
```

solution:
I must place `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file inside `public` directory.

but on reactjs, we haven't a `public` directory.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `react boilerplate`:

I added like this:

```
new OfflinePlugin({
  relativePaths: false,
  publicPath: '/',
  appShell: '/',
  ServiceWorker: {
    events: true,
    entry: path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/firebase-messaging-sw.js') //<-- path for your extended service worker
  },

  // No need to cache .htaccess. See http://mxs.is/googmp,
  // this is applied before any match in `caches` section
  excludes: ['.htaccess'],
```

I have a `push-notification.js` and I should call `firebase-messaging-sw.js` inside it:

```
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then((registration) => {
      firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration);
    });
```

two files are the same directory(app).
if you get the same error,

then:

```
app.js
`import 'file-loader?name=firebase-messaging-sw.js!./firebase-messaging-sw.js';`
```

Comment: I have been researching for countless of hours to resolve this problem, thank you very much for this !

Comment: what would be the possible solution when using with Angular 7?

Comment: i need more details to do push notification in react.js

Comment: `useServiceWorker` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

i am using react-boiler-plate which does not have public folder where we have to put the firebase-messaging-sw.js. In react-boiler-plate we have to put this code

```
new OfflinePlugin({
relativePaths: false,
publicPath: '/',
appShell: '/',
ServiceWorker: {
    events: true,
    entry: path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/firebase-messaging-sw.js') //<-- path for your extended service worker
},
```

inside

> internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js

and inside app.js we have to import like this

```
// firebase messaging
import 'file-loader?name=firebase-messaging-sw.js!./firebase-messaging-sw.js';
```

and it should work now :)